# How to Set the Working Directory in NAnt?

Tags: visual-studio, build-process, build, build-automation, nant

I am just getting started using NAnt. I was working from a tutorial, and just trying to set a target to clean my solution on build. My Visual Studio Solution structure is as follows:

- Solution Folder

  - Project Folder
  - Project Folder
  - Tools Folder

    - NAnt Folder

The NAnt .exe file resides in the Tools/NAnt folder. My .build file is also in there. Here is my .build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project name="NAntTest" default="build" xmlns="http://nant.sf.net/release/0.86-beta1/nant.xsd">
  <property name="solution.file.name" value="NAntTest.sln" />
  <property name="project.config" value="debug" />

  <target name="build" depends="clean.source" />

  <target name="clean.source">
    <exec program="${framework::get-framework-directory(framework::get-target-framework())}\msbuild.exe"
          commandline="${solution.file.name} /t:Clean /p:Configuration=${project.config} /v:q" 
          workingdir="."/>
  </target>

</project>
```

This is how the example I am following was formatted. If I try to run this build, I get an error stating that the project file does not exist. In the clean.source target, if I replace the workingdir attribute with a hard coded path to my base solution folder, the script compiles and runs correctly. Obviously, this is not ideal for portability if I need to move the project anywhere.

How do I get NAnt to see the base working directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My recommendation is to always place the build file at solution level. Then all relative paths in the build file will be equal to that of the solution.

Comment: Moving this up into the solution directory worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It'll work, but I mean, the advice isn't exactly sound.  Just set basedir appropriately.  (Btw, wasn't me that downvoted.)

Answer (score 7):

There is not builtin function to change the current directory, but you can create one in a script block :

```
  <target name="foo">
    <echo message="Current directory set to ${directory::set-current-directory('C:')}"/>
    <echo message="Current directory is now ${directory::get-current-directory()}"/>
  </target>

  <script language="C#" prefix="directory">
    <code><![CDATA[
    [Function("set-current-directory")]
    public static string SetCurrentDirectory(string path)
    {
      System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path);
      return path;
    }
    ]]></code>
  </script>
```

Of course, you should avoid relying on the current directory in your scripts or in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the basedir attribute of the project node.  This may resolve your problem.

```
<project name="NAntTest" default="build" basedir="C:\Code\MyProject" xmlns="http://nant.sf.net/release/0.86-beta1/nant.xsd">
```

Comment: You should probably set the basedir using a relative path (i.e. "..\..").

Comment: This is the correct answer, along with the comment to use a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the verbose attribute of the nant [exec task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html) then it will spit out the exact command line that it generated. Not sure what your specific problem is regarding executing msbuild - I've been using the [nantcontrib msbuild task](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc4/help/tasks/msbuild.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a `workingdir` attribute you can define on your `exec` element.

According to the [documentation](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html), `workingdir` refers to "The directory in which the command will be executed.".

Answer (score 0):

As a task instead of a function:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="test" default="build">
    <script language="C#" prefix="path" >
        <code>
            <![CDATA[
            [TaskName("set-current-directory")]
            public class SetCurrentDirectory : Task {
                private string _path;

                [TaskAttribute("path", Required=true)]
                public string Path {
                    get { return _path; }
                    set { _path = value; }
                }

                protected override void ExecuteTask() {
                    System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(_path);;
                }
            }
            ]]>
        </code>
    </script>

    <target name="build">
        <set-current-directory path="c:\Program Files" />
        <echo message="${directory::get-current-directory()}" />
     </target>
</project>
```

Output:

```
$ nant

build:

     [echo] c:\Program Files
```